# How to run multiple commands under one execution?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to run:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -codec copy vid.mp4 

ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -map 0:2 output_file.wav
```

And:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i output_file.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy new_test.mp4
```

I have tried using `&&` to run the first two commands parallel but it doesn’t work:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -codec copy vid.mp4 && vid.mkv -codec copy vid.mp3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which shell are you using? In most \*nix shells `&&` is used to run the second command only when the first one succeeded

Comment: Do you maybe want a single `ffmpeg` to do all this and to read `vid.mkv` only once in the process?

Comment: This set of commands doesn't quite make sense if that's the case. Anyways, needs clarity for sure, unanswerable accurately as of now. Please describe what you actually need to achieve in more than 0 sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly do you mean by "under one execution".

either

`cmd1; cmd2; cmd3`
or
`cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`

will run those commands **sequentially**. The difference between ';' and '&&' is mentioned here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187145/whats-the-difference-between-semicolon-and-double-ampersand